# segmentation and count using group by

Tags: mysql

I have a table like

```
uid programid
1   3
1   4
2   5
2   6
3   3
...
```

but imagine that on one million line, what I would like to get is something like
[image]

Is this possible doing that using mysql ? Percentage is not that important but I would really appreciate to get  the 'cluster' part.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Not sure what you are asking about..i assume you asking how MySQL stores the data on disk?

Comment: Hi Raymond, not really. My point was to get a SQL query to get some stat.

Comment: *"not really. My point was to get a SQL query to get some stat. "* Next time see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pre-compute data using table expressions as shown below. If using MySQL 8.x you can use CTEs (that are friendlier to use). For example:

```
select
  favorites,
  users,
  case when users = 0 then 0 else mod(users - 1, 5) end as cluster
from (
   select
    favorites,
    count(*) as users
  from (
    select uid, count(*) as favorites
    from t
    group by uid
  ) x
  group by favorites
) y
order by favorites
```

Comment: Thanks a lor for this @the-impaler :) Do you have a MySQL 5.7 working query ?

Comment: @glmrenard This one is for MySQL 5.x. It does not use CTEs.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure to understand, where does the 't' in from t come from (same for x and y)

Comment: Replace `t` with the name of your table. You didn't specify the table name, so I used `t` as a placeholder.

Comment: It works, thank you so much @the-impaler, Now I need to think a lot in order to understand it, you saved my day !!

Comment: *"Now I need to think a lot in order to understand it"* @glmrenard little hint those subqueries (delivered table is the real term) in the `FROM ( ... )` clause can be executed solo, so you see what it does..